# Pandas create zip file from ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the error File Size would require Zip64 when running the following code.  The excel conversion is to large to save to disk to be later converted. Is there a way to zip before saving to disk?
I tried writer.book.use_zip64() but it will not work.  The result of the output from to_excel function is NoneType if assign it to a variable.

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')
    output_df.round(2)
    output_df.to_excel (writer, index = False, header=True)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I tried writer.book.use_zip64() but it will not work.

It should work. Here is a working example based on your snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd

output_df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

file_name ='pandas_simple.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
output_df.round(2)
output_df.to_excel(writer, index = False, header=True )

writer.book.use_zip64()

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I would see a file with a zip extension in place of the xlsx.

Comment: I have the same issue, but this solution does not seem to work on Databricks. Any idea?

Comment: For Databricks see this limitation/workaround with `copyfile()`: https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations